# I'm trying to load data from oracle to SQl server in Ssis 2008 R2. In between I'm using Data conversion transformation for converting

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to load data from oracle to SQl server in Ssis 2008  R2. In between I'm using Data conversion transformation for converting an varchar2 data to DT_TEXT. Here I'm getting an error

> Description: Data conversion failed while converting column "PROJECT_DESC" (1762) to column "Copy of PROJECT_DESC" (1638).  The conversion returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.

the length of the particular record is around 948 and the maximum length allowed is around 2000.
Can someone please let me know what is going wrong here.

Comment: Essentially your problem is that you told SSIS that `PROJECT_DESC` is a `varchar 2` and the row is actually 948 characters wide thus you have truncation, thus you have error.

Answer (score 0):

The width of the new field "Copy of PROJECT_DESC" defined in the Data Conversion is smaller than the source field "PROJECT_DESC" being read from Oracle.  This is why it is warning of a truncation.  Determine the length of the source varchar2 field in Oracle and then change the new field "Copy of PROJECT_DESC" to match in the Data Conversion.

Hope this helps.